# Ruby unit tests - help using testResults object

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am currently teaching myself ruby and engaged in writing unit tests. 
I start by requiring and inheriting from `Test::Unit::TestCase`

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestAuth < Test::Unit::TestCase
```

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/TestCase.html it says:

```
It also does the nitty-gritty of actually running an individual test and
collecting its results into a Test::Unit::TestResult object.
```

My question is probably a simple one to answer but I cant seem to find any examples of it. How do I access that `TestResult` object?

In all examples I see I don't see anyone accessing the `TestResult` object. I want to create, from the object, a results file similar to junits result file so my tests can be run and recorded in a continuous integration system like bamboo or jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Check [ci_reporter](https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter) gem. It's unusual to me accessing the `TestResult` object directly.